# web.config file reverting to previous after build?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm having a puzzling problem with my `web.config` file on Visual Studio 2015. I open the project, open the `web.config` file and update a connection string to point to a different database source. I save the change and then close the `web.config` file. If I open back up the `web.config` file, the updates that I made are still there. But after I do a build, if I open the `web.config` file my update has reverted to what was there previously. Any ideas why?

Comment: Simply check the before bulid events. Do right click on the solution and chose properties. Then go tu build-events tab. You may have some scripts there to modify the web.config before or after the build

Comment: You should take a look at your config transformation files. They overwrite web.config.

Comment: @Mahdi Maybe i'm wrong, but i think the transformation files are only considered on publish, they are useless on simple builds

Comment: Agree with @Rumpelstinsk, I too have had this and it was a nant task setup as a pre build event.

Comment: I don't see any build events listed in the Properties window?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  Turns out there was a modification to the default setup in my .csproj file...

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Template.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>
```

This generates the web.config file at Build time based on Web.debug.config, Web.release.config, etc.

As described in this article:  http://www.kongsli.net/2012/01/13/enabling-web-transforms-when-debugging-asp-net-apps/

Answer (score 2):

You may have 'Web.Debug.config' or 'Web.Release.config' file in the project folder. In my case, I updated the database configuration value in 'Web.Debug.config' file when using debug mode then solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your case, but there is an "applicationhost.config" file in the "\YourAppName\.vs\config" folder that should be off the root of your project. Make sure all the links there are pointing to the current solution.

This just happened to me because I made a copy of an existing project to a new location and modified it. I came back after successful builds suddenly and ALL my web.config settings reverted to the original copy. Every node in the "web.config" matched to a "T". I edited any references from the old location to the new and hopefully this will no longer be an issue. This file apparently is not included in the search as it didn't come up when I looked for the old path within my project. Make sure you do a search for the old path also, just to be sure that it is not going to be an issue.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try removing folder "obj" in the project's directory then rebuild the project.

**Folder location:**
$(ProjectDir)obj